# UDP communication through device and qt emulator

Tags: qt, udp, emulation

I am creating an app that sends a simple string through `UDPsocket`. I am using QT to develop it. The problem I'm having is that, I don't have a second device to test my application. It is possible to use my own phone as the one device(server or client) and the Qt emulator for the second ? Because I think that there will be problems with the `IP` and `PORT` for the communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one Socket Simulator which can run on your machine. I always test sockets using [Socket Test Software](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sockettest/). You need to install Java to run this software. This can run of your Windows, MAC or Linux machine. While testing you can use `IP` as `127.0.0.1`, that is `localhost` and `PORT` you can assign at your Server end. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Just checked it!!seems really helpfull, i can send sockets through my phone right??!

Comment: your phone and PC running this App should be in same network then you need to give server IP at client end